# Using Backbone.history to go back

Tags: backbone.js

I have inherited a half-finished mobile app built using Backbone.js (which I have never used).

I need, quite simply, to send the user back when they click a back button.

Some brief research leads me to believe it has something to do with `Backbone.history` but I can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Unless the app uses the fancy-schmancy HTML5 [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history#pushState) events, I don't see a need for [`Backbone.History`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History) here. Just use [`window.history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history#back).

Comment: Just a heads up.  This will throw a wrench in GoogleAnalytics.  The historychange GA event will fire when the URL is updated, which will be before the page title is updated.

Answer (score 41):

Nowadays you can also use some more Backbone with `Backbone.history.history` which provides you methods like `.forward`, `.go` and finally `Backbone.history.history.back()`.

Comment: Yeah, with two `.history()`, trust me.

Comment: `Backbone.history.history === window.history`
`.forward`, `.go`, and `.back` are all native to `window.history`

Comment: A better answer than accepted answer IMO. OP is using Backbone, so I feel it would be best to stick with using Backbone for back navigation in this scenario.