# What is the best way to implement back functionality in SPA with Backbone Router?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router

Today is 2015 year and I'm again looking for best practices to implement `back` functionality in my Backbone SPA application.

I've found a lot of questions around this one but all of them very old. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860461/selective-history-back-using-backbone-js) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732223/using-backbone-history-to-go-back) These questions from back 2012/2013 years. Since backbone has a lot of changes so I need to know what is the best way to implement `back` functionality today?

Thanks

Comment: In 2.5 years backbone has only bumped two minor versions from 1.0.0 in march 2013 to 1.2.1 in june 2015. What are these changes you refer to that stops you from using the linked answers? What specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: I Thought backbone has now something like `router.back()` or similar because it's common task in SPA.